# Ceiling Fan Capacitor Replacement

Tags: ceiling, ceiling-fan

I need to change out a ceiling fan capacitor, but cannot find exact replacement. 4.5uf(280v)+ 5uf (250v)+5uf(250v)....4 wire, per picture. What would be suggested replacement, based on if & the 280v to 250v?[image]

Comment: Tried Galco in Madison Heights MI?

Answer (score 2):

I found a cbb61 in about 10 seconds 5,5,4.5uf the same as you have for 6.29$ the wire colors may be different but that's not a problem it has 2 gray wires on the one side but you don't have to use both, just wire nut the extra off or put both under the same nut. On a 120v circuit 250v will be fine.

Comment: Does it have to be 5,5,4.5 or can it be 4.5,5,5?